# Null reply from hiredis command on simple C code

Tags: c, redis, hiredis

I installed Redis server using below commands on Kali Linux 2019.4:

```
$ redisurl="http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz"
$ curl -s -o redis-stable.tar.gz $redisurl
$ sudo su root
$ mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/
$ chmod a+w /usr/local/lib/
$ tar -C /usr/local/lib/ -xzf redis-stable.tar.gz
$ rm redis-stable.tar.gz
$ cd /usr/local/lib/redis-stable/
$ make && make install
```

and then on `redis-cli` when I Enter **PING**, it replies **PONG**

But when i use below C code with using `hiredis`, it replies `null`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <hiredis/hiredis.h>

redisContext *c;
redisReply *reply;
void main() {

    c = redisConnect("127.0.0.1", 6379);
    reply = redisCommand(c,"PING");
    printf("PING: %s \n", reply->str);

}
```

The output: `PING: (null)`

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Since you can already run redis-cli, do so running `monitor` which should tell you straight away whether your server is receiving your request from your C code. Obviously if that isn't working, nothing else will. Actually *checking* your redis call success/failure would probably be of great benefit as well, lest you violate Spencer' 6th Commandment.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Tanks for your reply, when i use `hset` command, it effects on server but null reply received from server on all commands.

Comment: Strings aren't the only reply type. If there is an error state (or something else) it will be reflected in the reply object. And since there is no HSET command issued in your posted code, I'll ignore that for now and just stick with what you have above. The `type` field in particular is worth inspecting. Get a debugger and start peeking at members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all, Do you run Redis as a service in the background on the correct port?**

I think if you want to start with new things, it's better, to begin with, those examples that were already tested. And, If you got an error again probably your Redis upstarting not truly done.

Please look at the below links carefully and pay more attention to those examples:

https://github.com/redis/hiredis

https://github.com/redis/hiredis/tree/master/examples

I hope it could be helpful.